# getResult() of TRUNCATE in Doctrine 2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

What does Doctrine's getResult() function actually return when the issued query was a TRUNCATE TABLE statement? The API does not give me any answers. 
The code I'm running is this:

```
$result = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'TRUNCATE snmptt'
        )->getResult();
```

Comment: So you didn't try it? Than you would know the answer ...

Comment: That is true. By doing so I found out that this doesn't work at all, because createQuery() expects SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this doesn't work at all, because the createQuery() statement can only contain SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE .